# fetching content from CMS to Salesforce marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

we have a content management system Magnolia where all the email contents are being created, i have to fetch the content from CMS and push it to marketing cloud. Is there a way to achieve this? i have been going though the rest api documents for the same but not able to get any help.

Please let me know if you guys have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways you can integrate these. An assumption is that you want to create a copy of the asset in Marketing Cloud.

So you could use

```
POST /asset/v1/content/assets
```

More info here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/#detail_CreateAsset

You could create a window from Marketing Cloud to your CMS and then push/create the asset from your CMS to Content Builder.

Look up about creating custom apps in the app center. What you are trying to do is possible. Enquire with the vendor if they already have an integration/package